# Choosing the right partition by rule

Tags: mysql, database-design, partitioning

I have the following table:

```
`CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
 `uid_from` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `uid_to` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `counter` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `updated` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid_to`,`uid_from`, `updated`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`
```

Which I would like to partition by the `updated` field in order easily delete old data and allow queries that are in a specific time-frame.

I'm planning on mostly querying along this condition
`WHERE user_id_to=X AND updated> DATE_SUB(NOW() < INTERVAL 3 MONTH)`

I'm a bit unsure about what `partition by` rule I should create, and if have to also include in it the `uid_to` field or not.

Comment: Why do you think you need partitions instead of an index on the "updated" column? (Or, more likely, an index on the pair uid_to, updated?)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'